# how to downgrade symfony2 bundles knp_compnent?

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I am new and facing issue with "Manual counting" which is not working in KnpPaginatorBundle and I got solution that I have to downgrade my bundle but I even do not know how to downgrade knplabs/knp-components or knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle. Some one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us which version currently do you have or to which version you would like to downgrade for that matter.

However, follow these simple steps:

- Go to [Packagist's knp-components page](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-components)
- Find the exact version you would like to downgrade to
- Put that version tag into your `composer.json`
- Run `php composer.phar update "knplabs/knp-components"`

Alternatively, you could remove `knp-componets` altogether and install it again but that is kinda unnecessary.

### EDIT:

Based on your comment I see what seems to be a problem you're experiencing. I can think of two ways to resolve this:

1. Download `.tar` of current `knp-components` and downgraded `knp-paginator` and put them in your src. Remove `knp-paginator` from your composer dependency list and update vendors. I advice against this.
2. Fork the `knplabs/knp-paginator` project to your own and edit their `composer.json` file by specifying desired `knplabs/knp-componets` version. Then insert your fork into your `composer.json` and update vendors. This is by all means preferable way of doing it.

Hope this helps.

### EDIT2:

Referencing your fork via `VCS`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/modernmonkslab/KnpPaginatorBundle1"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

This should work, given that your fork is `public`.

Comment: I did not have "knplabs/knp-components" entry in my composer.json file it comes as a dependency with "knplabs/knp-paginator".

Comment: Ah, I see. I had edited my answer to include some alternative solutions.

Comment: I am trying with your 2nd option, I have created my fork here https://github.com/modernmonkslab/KnpPaginatorBundle.

Comment: Great! I assume you had to register your fork on `packagist.org`?

Comment: I am getting this "package with the name knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle already exists." when i am adding https://github.com/modernmonkslab/KnpPaginatorBundle1.git

Comment: They are saying this - "Do not submit forks of existing packages. If you need to test changes to a package that you forked to patch, use VCS Repositories instead. If however it is a real long-term fork you intend on maintaining feel free to submit it." and I am using VCS as type. but my doubt is how can we use my repository just for single package not for all.

Comment: You're right. I forgot about limitation when it comes to submitting forks to packagist. And another "yes" for referencing package via `VCS`, I have done it before (even with my private repos). See this link: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: Added the example above ;)

Comment: Jovan Perovic thanks for your my task is done, I like this community

Comment: Don't mention it. Welcome to SO :)